# How to point domain to VPS when A Records are not available

Tags: domain, vps, nameserver, cname

I have bought a domain and VPS from two different providers. To host this domain on VPS, I need to create A Record in domain control panel that points to VPS IP (this is what I was told by VPS provider).

Problem is domain registrar doesn't have the option to create A Record (it's a ccTLD). They say you can only update nameservers in domain.

In this situation how can I host my domain on VPS? Any solution like some free DNS, nameserver etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the issue is that domain registration is different to domain delegation (dns) service - although many providers do both.

It appears your domain provider is only offering registration services. The solution is to find a provider that offers dns service and then use them. (Either shift the domain to them or get their nameserver details and add these to the registration service you have).  You then set up the A record in the DNS.

(If you have at least 2 VPS's you can run your own nameservers on each, but it's a lot of learning and probably not a great idea.)

Comment: I found a number of free DNS providers such as namecheap.com, cloudflare.com, afraid.org etc.